# Installing R-base in Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, r

I'm trying to install the package r-base using the [Linux Mint community](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/r-base) software view.

By clicking on the "install" button one asks me for the "install of additional software?". By clicking on "install" again, the following error message comes out:

```
Can not install 'r-base' (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
```

This is the output of `apt-cache policy`:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-webupd8team-java,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Oracle Java (JDK) 7 / 8 / 9 Installer PPA,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-webupd8team-java,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Oracle Java (JDK) 7 / 8 / 9 Installer PPA,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://repository.spotify.com/ stable/non-free i386 Packages
     release v=0.4,o=Spotify LTD,a=stable,n=stable,l=Spotify Public Repository,c=non-free
     origin repository.spotify.com
 500 http://repository.spotify.com/ stable/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=0.4,o=Spotify LTD,a=stable,n=stable,l=Spotify Public Repository,c=non-free
     origin repository.spotify.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner Translation-en
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Partner archive,c=partner
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Partner archive,c=partner
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Translation-en
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 700 http://extra.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/main i386 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=main
     origin extra.linuxmint.com
 700 http://extra.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/main amd64 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=main
     origin extra.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/import i386 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=import
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/upstream i386 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=upstream
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/main i386 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=main
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/import amd64 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=import
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/upstream amd64 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=upstream
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ rebecca/main amd64 Packages
     release v=17.1,o=linuxmint,a=rebecca,n=rebecca,l=linuxmint,c=main
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     release v=12.04,o=CRAN,a=precise,n=precise,l=CRAN,c=
     origin cran.stat.ucla.edu
Pinned packages:
```

This is the output of `apt-cache policy r-base`:

```
r-base:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.1.3-1precise2
  Version table:
     3.1.3-1precise2 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.1.2-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.1.1-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.1.0-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.3.20140328-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.3-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.2-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
     3.0.2-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-6precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-5precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-3precise 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-1precise0precise2 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.0-2precise 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     2.15.3-1precise0precise1 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     2.15.2-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     2.15.1-1precise2 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     2.15.0-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
```

and, finally, this is the output for the `sudo apt-get install r-base` code:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.1.3-1precise2) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.1.3-1precise2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The following one is the output of the sudo apt-cache policy r-base-core r-recommended:

```
r-base-core:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.1.3-1precise2
  Version table:
     3.1.3-1precise2 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.1.2-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.1.1-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.1.0-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.3.20140328-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.3-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.2-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
     3.0.2-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-6precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-5precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-3precise 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-1precise0precise2 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.0-2precise 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     2.15.3-1precise0precise1 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     2.15.2-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     2.15.1-1precise2 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     2.15.0-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
r-recommended:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.1.3-1precise2
  Version table:
     3.1.3-1precise2 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.1.2-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.1.1-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.1.0-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.3.20140328-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.3-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.2-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
     3.0.2-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-6precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-5precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-3precise 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-1precise0precise2 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     3.0.0-2precise 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     2.15.3-1precise0precise1 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     2.15.2-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     2.15.1-1precise2 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     2.15.0-1precise0 0
        500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
```

while the following one is the output from the terminal of the command `sudo apt-get install r.base-core`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libtiff4 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The output from the `sudo apt-cache policy libtiff4 is:

```
libtiff4:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

and from `sudo apt-get install libtiff4 is:

```
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libtiff4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libtiff4' has no installation candidate
```

I tried to install it by using the software manager too, but without success.

Browsing on the internet I found some code to install it by using Ubuntu 12.10+ through the terminal, but nothing adapt to Linux Mint (or, at least, I think it was not).

Does someone knows how to install the R software or suggest the correct procedure to do it, please?

Comment: Please post the output of `apt-cache policy` and `apt-cache policy r-base`, and `dpkg -C`, please.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @FaheemMitha. I editd the question by inserting what you requested. There's no output from the code dpkg -C (may be I'm in wrong about the command!)

Comment: Ok, please paste the output of `apt-get install r-base`. If ` dpkg -C` gives no output it just means that there is no dpkg level package breakage, so that is fine.

Comment: I posted it too by editing right now; thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Ok, now post `apt-cache policy r-base-core r-recommended`. Also post the output of `apt-get install r-base-core`.

Comment: Ok, now the output of `apt-cache policy libtiff4` and `apt-get install libtiff4`. Note that in general people don't know you have updated the question unless you ping them.

Comment: ok @FaheemMitha I didn't know it! Anyway I posted what you requested.

Comment: It might be faster if you were to hop into the main chat room - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux You can ping me from there. And I want `apt-cache show r-base-core` next. But that could be quite large - you can paste it in chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `apt-cache policy` included:

```
500 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ precise/ Packages
     release v=12.04,o=CRAN,a=precise,n=precise,l=CRAN,c=
     origin cran.stat.ucla.edu
```

The problem was that the CRAN sources were for "precise", whereas they should have been for "trusty". The poster is running Mint version 17.1 Rebecca. This is compatible with "trusty", but not with "precise". After changing this CRAN source to "trusty", the poster reported the problem was solved.